# How to extract slides from a video using python

Tags: python, video, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing

I have a video training course supplied as AVI files. Most of the screens are shown as slides with a mouse pointer moving around on them.

I'd like to capture a screenshot of the slide automatically when the screen changes (ignoring when the image changes a small amount due to the mouse pointer moving around.)

I want to do this so I can paste the images into a word or html document that I can add notes to as I learn as at the moment I'm taking screenshots but it's very slow and tedious and the course is very long (around 24 hours total play time).

I know python well but am unsure as to how I would go about extracting stills from a video file and then how to compare one still with another to see how much they differ to decide which to keep and which to discard.

Can anyone suggest how to go about doing this?

Comment: I have built a python package for this called `slide-extractor` which does exactly what you are trying to do. You can see it here https://pypi.org/project/slide-extractor/1.0.0/ . You can also take inspiration from its source code if you want to make something like this on your own

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A tool like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is suited for extracting images from a video. From the manual:

```
 ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
```

This will extract one video frame per second from the video and
will output them in files named `foo-001.jpeg`, `foo-002.jpeg`, etc.
Images will be rescaled to fit the new WxH values.

Comparing them for differences can then perhaps be done by [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and/or [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

**EDIT:** I just realized that it probably would be more efficient to only grab the [key frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame#Video_compression) (intra frame), because those occur when a drastic change in the scene happens. A quick google later we have this:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi -vsync 0 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
```

Comment: thanks. the second example I couldn't get to work, even with the latest version of ffmpeg. The first example works for what I need.

Comment: @zio Please make sure you set the desired Width and Height parameters (WxH) i.e 1280x720  the final command will look like this:

./ffmpeg -i foo.avi -vsync 0 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -s 1280x720 -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg

Comment: I got `Invalid frame size: WxH.` when running the first command on a mp4 video file.

Answer (score 5):

What you basically want is scene detection. [framedifferenceanalyzer](http://code.google.com/p/framedifferenceanalyzer/) is an educational proof of concept in Python that does exactly that, and should provide a good starting point for learning about the problem itself.

As for implementing it yourself, [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is the ideal tool for converting a video into a sequence of frames - I probably wouldn't attempt doing that part in pure Python.

For calculating the difference between frames you could maybe use ImageMagick (its [compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) tool in particular). There are several Python bindings for ImageMagick, for example [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/) or [magickwand](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/magickwand) to name just two.

You could also use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to do the image analysis. OpenCV is a library of high performance, high quality computer vision algorithms and probably one of, if not the most powerful tool out there to do things like this. However, it kind of assumes that you have a certain knowledge about computer vision / image processing and already have a good idea of what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks. the compare tool works great for me along with imagemagick in python.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons to extract slides/frames from a video presentation, especially in the case of education or conference related videos. It allows you to access the study notes without watching the whole video.

I have faced this issue several times, so I decided to create a solution for it myself using python. I have made the code open-source, you can easily set up this tool and run it in few simple steps.

Refer to this for a [youtube video tutorial](https://youtu.be/Q0BIPYLoSBs).
Steps on how to use this tool.

- Clone [this project](https://github.com/kaushikj/video2pdfslides)
- Set up your environment by running "pip install -r requirements.txt"
- Copy your video path
- Run "python video2pdfslides.py <video_path>"

Boom! the pdf slides will be available in the output folder Make notes and enjoy!